# Is it possible to create an SSO connection from BigCommerce to another SaaS platform?

Tags: single-sign-on, bigcommerce

I'm trying to determine if it's possible to do single sign-on (SSO) ***from*** BigCommerce ***to*** another SaaS platform?

I have not used BigCommerce yet and I need to suss this out for an upcoming project. I will need the ability to create a JWT token in BigCommerce to log users in to an LMS called Thinkific. The only documentation I see online about this refers to creating an SSO connection ***to*** BigCommerce.

Any insights on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use BigCommerce as an Identity Provider, you will need to verify the credentials using either the REST API (https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/store-management/customers-v3/customer-validate-credentials/customervalidatecredentials) or using GraphQL using the login mutation (https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/storefront/graphql)

The use of a JWT would be useful the other way round, using a third party to authenticate for login into BC.

Comment: Thank you @SimonPallister. Will look into these resources.